How to open KDE System Monitor using Ctrl+Shift+Esc in SteamOS?
I'm use to opening my Task Manager with Ctrl+Shift+Esc on Windows 11.
Is there a way I can set a shortcut key for the KDE System Monitor app so that it also opens using the same Ctrl+Shift+Esc shortcut on SteamOS Desktop Mode?
If it's not possible, is there perhaps a default shortcut key for the KDE System Monitor app that I can use to open it?

You can set up keybinds in Settings > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > Edit > New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL and enter plasma-systemmonitor
More info here
https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/hotkeys

So there isn't a default shortcut to open it already? I need to make one?
